# show previous loaded tiles while loading(zoom in or zoom out) map

Tags: css, dictionary, openlayers, geospatial, geoserver

Friends..

How can we remove the white tile part(map loading area)..
[image]
While zoom in and zoom out white tile part is appearing on the map(map loading area).
How can we fill that area with the history image of that area?

And is there any better method to fast load maps than GeoWebCache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transitionEffect configuration option for the layer

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Grid-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.transitionEffect